# Letsencrypt SSL on node and rails app on same DigitalOcean droplet. Works for rails but not for node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have two apps, one is a rails app which uses Let's encrypt for SSL and nginx as the server. It's deployed on Digital Ocean.
I've also added a simple node app (for a complimenting feature to my rails app) built using Express which listens to port 8080.

I want my node app to use the same SSL certificate as my rails app.
How do I do it by configuring it with nginx? or is there a better way to achieve that?

Here is my nginx config file.

```
server {
                listen 443 ssl;
            server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/mydomain/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to genererate 2 certificates, one for each app, specifying the different ports or subdomains. Then you need the 2 different nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name abc.xyz www.abc.xyz;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.xyz/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.abc.xyz;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abc.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abc.xyz/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```